# How do I return php html in proper order?

Tags: php

I am trying to display the result of a function on a page in the order of stylesheet, image and menu. But for some reason it is outputting the code in the order of styles, menu, image. Here is the code...

```
$html = '';
$html .= show_styles();
$html .= '<img src="..." alt="..." >';
$html .= show_menu();

return $html;
```

Why is it doing this?

PS - this is not a CSS issue, the is the actual source code order I am concerned with.

Comment: What does `var_dump(show_styles(), '<img src="..." alt="..." >', show_menu())` display to you?

Comment: What do `show_styles()` and `show_menu()` do? Do they `return` values or do they `echo` them?

Comment: they echo them, is that the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show_styles()` and `show_menu()` are probably `echo`ing out the their output not `return`ing it.  Look if they have parameters that can determine whether result is `echo`ed or `return`ed. If you can change it to `return` then your code works.

If they only `echo` and you can't change it, you can capture the output:

```
$html = '';

ob_start();
show_styles();
$html .= ob_get_clean();

$html .= '<img src="..." alt="..." >';

ob_start();
show_menu();
$html .= ob_get_clean();
```